# Efficient way to apply conditions/rules to a csv file

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a CSV file on the employee for example

```
employee id, employee name, city, state, salary
```

Let's say I want to apply a bunch of conditions for ex: if the city is "Toronto" increment salary by 100. And let's say I have 100 such rules, I'd have to write 100 if/else condition.

What's would be the most efficient way to apply those rules to the data in the CSV file and update the file?

Comment: Nothing beats going line by line. You can use multiprocessng and bench mark against single threaded code, but based on filesize it would be overkill.

Comment: Since you haven't added any "only python way" anywhere, I would recommend you to use pandas for it. It is fast and you will get one-liner for this

Comment: I updated the question. I am trying to solve 2 things, let's say I have 100 rules then I may probably have 100 if/else, how can this be avoided plus the fastest way to process and apply these rules. Can pandas take care of the 100 rules?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to do this

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# if the city is "Toronto" increment salary by 100
df.loc[df['city'] == 'Toronto', 'salary'] += 100

# ...
# Other rules

df.to_csv('chaged.csv')
```